# How to find font and replace with highlight

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding Application.Findformat.font I am trying to find font **Winding2** and highlight yellow. I was able to put something together to find and delete windings. The next step is to highlight wherever a winding exists. Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
Cells.Select
    With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Subscript = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
       Selection.Replace What:="P", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Subscript = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With application.replaceformat.font
        .Name="Arial"
     End With
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

try this you could have got this by recording macro in your excel.

Comment: Sivaprasath V  With the code you gave me above, I was able to highlight Windings, but the code won't replace them? Regardless, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to use the .Font object to replace the font. Interior object only changes the interior formats. You can use the .Font object with .Name property to change the font

Comment: My VBA knowledge is very limited. I will try research and see what I come up with. The code above is great and will suffice for now. My hope is to have the ability to replace Windings and highlight. We use the checkmarks for edit check purposes etc. Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I am changing the font from windings 2 to Arial and highlighting to yellow.. you can record macros from your developer tab and get the codes.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for your help and support!

Comment: Thanks for your help.